# В среде разработки поймать try catch

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

В этом коде, а точнее в блоке try {} выпадает ошибка

```
try {
    data = (char*)realloc(data, value);
}
catch (...) {
    data = (char*)realloc(data, value);
}
```

Хочу поставить метку в блоке catch, чтобы отловить ошибку. Почему то в Visual Studio не работает... Нужны какие-то настройки?

Многие пишут, что realloc не даёт исключений... ещё как даёт, вот простейший пример:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"


int main()
{
    char *a = (char*)malloc(10);
    free(a);
    a = (char*)realloc(a, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Должно ловить. Попробуйте поставить явно `DebugBreak();`

Comment: в этом коде не может быть C++ исключений, поэтому ловить нужно [системные исключения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Они не ловятся простым catch.

Comment: `realloc` бросает исключения?

Comment: да, realloc ...

Comment: С каких пор? nothrow же

Comment: @sitev_ru, покажите пожалуйста документацию, в которой это написано.

Comment: nick_n_a, поставил DebugBreak, как теперь попасть отладкой в catch{} ?

Comment: user1056837, зачем документация, в реале вылетает

Comment: `try/catch` никакого отношения ни к какому "отлавливанию ошибок" не имеет, а функция `realloc` исключений не выбрасывает. И, кстати, что здесь делает тэг [C]?

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, показал, что realloc генерирует исключения

Comment: Это не исключение, это Undefined Behavior, грубая ошибка на сторона программиста. Её не нужно ловить, её нужно не допускать.

Comment: Как её ловить, если не try catch?

Comment: @sitev_ru: Никак. `try/catch` никогда не продназначался для ловли неожиданных падений в программе. А исключением в С++ назвается именно ситуация, когда код делает `throw`. `realloc` ничего не знает про `throw`, поэтому он его делать никак не может. Разношерстные "вылеты" в программе к С++ исключениям никакого отношения не имеют. (Читайте про SEH, если хотите, но это не `try/catch` и не С++).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начнем с того, что `realloc` никаких исключений не генерирует.
Продолжим тем, что если даже вы обратитесь по нулевому адресу - это будет не исключение C++, а вовсе даже * асинхронное структурированное исключение*. К которому `try/catch` не имеет отношения.
Но если очень хочется - то [в VC++ можно использовать ключик `/EHa`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1deeycx5.aspx), который позволяет `try/catch` ловить и эти исключения. Попробуйте с ним...

Но, откровенно говоря, я бы не рекомендовал им пользоваться - неприятностей больше, чем выгоды.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, показал, что realloc генерирует исключения

Comment: Издеваетесь, да? Вы сделали чистейший! классический! undefined behaviour - и не более того! Данный компилятор в данной операционной системе сделал аварийный останов - это исключение? Вы просто не разобрались в терминах...

Comment: ОК, это не исключение... Но как его поймать?

Comment: Ну я же вам написал - если хотите ловить его как исключение (на вашу ответственность!) - ключик `/EHa` (в Visual C++), и сбой по памяти (если он будет! между прочим, этот код имеет шанс и **не** вызвать сбоя, а сбой окажется совсем в другом месте...) будет превращен в исключение...

Answer (score 3):

> Многие пишут, что realloc не даёт исключений... ещё как даёт, вот простейший пример:

Вы наблюдаете багу в своем коде, но решили, что это исключение. Что же на самом деле происходит.

```
// тут выделили память, все ок.
char *a = (char*)malloc(10);
// освободили память, тоже ок. Но free не меняет значение указателя. Он продолжает указывать на тот же кусок памяти.
free(a);
// а теперь пытаемся обратиться к этой памяти...
a = (char*)realloc(a, 20);
```

Что на самом деле делает realloc? если сильно упростить, то он выделяет новую память нужного размера, копирует старую память на новое место, а старую память освобождает. Но любой программист знает, что если сделать дважды free для указателя - получишь ошибку. Примерный код [realloc](http://www.beedub.com/Sprite093/src/lib/c/stdlib/realloc.c) можно подсмотреть и там нет никаких явных бросаний исключений.

Так что же за "исключение"? Отладчик и компилятор знают о том, что программист может сделать ошибку. И в дебажном режиме добавляют всяких проверок.  И если что то происходит не так - сразу перехватывает.

То есть, Вы видите исключение не от realloc, а он дебажного менеджера памяти и отладчика, которые перехватили ситуацию двойного освобождения памяти (а может обращение к освобожденной памяти, но это менее вероятно) и ругают Вас.